# how to tell oracle sql treat & as data not as bing variable

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have to update columns in a table with data. And in one of column's data has & in it like( 'Salt & Pepper').

So when I run the update statement, it is prompting me to enter the value.

But in my case, it should not ask, it should insert the data 'Salt & Pepper' into the table's column.

```
UPDATE dishes SET ingredient = 'Salt & Pepper' WHERE dish_id = 5000;
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL*Plus, it is `SET DEFINE OFF`

```
SQL> UPDATE dishes SET ingredient = 'Salt & Pepper' WHERE dish_id = 5000;
Enter value for pepper:
old   1: UPDATE dishes SET ingredient = 'Salt & Pepper' WHERE dish_id = 5000
new   1: UPDATE dishes SET ingredient = 'Salt ' WHERE dish_id = 5000

1 row updated.
```

But:

```
SQL> set def off
SQL> UPDATE dishes SET ingredient = 'Salt & Pepper' WHERE dish_id = 5000;

1 row updated.

SQL>
```

Tool you use might have different option, but - generally speaking - it comes to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

use SET ESCAPE:
    SET ESC[APE] {OFF | ON | escape_char}

so:

```
SET ESCAPE ON
SET ESCAPE "\"
UPDATE dishes SET ingredient = 'Salt \& Pepper' WHERE dish_id = 5000;
```

should do the trick, I think.